# How can I resolve absent Form Data in Google Picker API request?

Tags: google-api, google-picker

Some of my users cannot use Google Picker in my web application. At this point, I've tried a bunch of different things. Nothing has worked. So, I'd like to drill down on one fundamental difference.

Users whose requests succeed have requests that take this form:

```
Query String Parameters

hl: en_US
xtoken: <redacted>
origin: http://localhost:3000
oauth_token: <redacted>
hostId: localhost
 

Form Data

start: 0
numResults: 50
sort: 3
desc: true
cursor:
mine: 2
service: docs
type: EVERYTHING
options: {"notInFolder":true,"mimeTypes":"application/msword,application/vnd.google-apps.document,application/vnd.google-apps.kix,application/vnd.ms-word,application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12,application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroenabled.12,application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12,application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroenabled.12,application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template,text/plain,application/vnd.google-apps.folder","ff":true}
token: <redacted>
version: 4
app: 2
subapp: 5
clientUser: <redacted>
```

Users whose requests fail have requests that take this form (no form data):

```
Query string parameters

protocol: gadgets
origin: http://localhost:3000
multiselectEnabled: true
oauth_token: <redacted>
hostId: localhost
parent: http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico
nav: (("documents",null,{"includeFolders":true}),("upload",null,{"query":"docs"}))
rpcService: <redacted>
rpctoken: <redacted>
thirdParty: true
ppli: 2
```

The `Uncaught Error: xb at m=opnc:1067` error produced by the minified version of picker following this request comes from the part of the module which loads `"gapi.iframes"`:

```js
yt.prototype.init = function(a) {
            var b = this;
            this.O = a;
            this.N = this.V.load("gapi.iframes").then(function(c) {
                return c.JV.getContext()
            }).then(function(c) {
                return c && c.getParentIframe()
            }).then(function(c) {
                if (!c) // C does not exist for me!!!!
                    throw Error("xb"); // So, I get this error.
                return c
            });
            return this.N.then(function(c) {
                return void eoa(b, c)
            })
        }
```

I have no idea why Picker is producing different requests. The logic on my end is the same, and the OAuth token is always successfully fetched. Why might this be happening?

Comment: This behaviour may originate in a environment with disabled cookies. Could you please check if the users with failed requests have enabled all cookies?

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron Yeah, we've checked a couple times. As far as we can tell all cookies are enabled for all affected users.

With the latest set of updates, this API only appears to be working for me, the developer and GCP admin. I'd thought this might be a dev key issue, but I don't know how to fix that. Settings have been changed since the key was originally generated. Would I have to regen?

All affected users have been added as tests users.

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron FYI, regenning did not make a difference.

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron I can confirm that the affected users receive different cookies than the ones who can use picker successfully. However, none of these cookies are blocked.

Comment: I *think that error is auth-related. In my particular setting, the picker loads fine in the browser but fails in Electron (requires a new sign in). I get this exact same error `Uncaught Error: xb at m=opnc:1067`, and swapping out for a different set of oauth credentials (generated from a slack login, also running in electron) bypasses the problem.

Comment: @AlvinWan Saw you commented on my other post as well. This fails in my browser too. I am using `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token` to get the oauthToken at the moment. Would you be willing to share what worked for you in a private chat?

Comment: I actually haven't solved it yet unfortunately. I think we're facing the same problem though (my electron setup is probably similar to your users')

From the debugger, it looks like `c.getParentIframe()` is returning `null`. Not sure what this has to do with creds, but it looks like message passing between the webpage and the within-iframe js is failing?

Comment: I've faced this issue for about the last month, and tried a bunch of different support channels. I ran into a similar issue a few months prior that ended up being a conflict with an extension (Disconnect). Maybe try looking into that for yourself. Talking to Workspace Developer Support rn. So, let's keep our fingers crossed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate this scenario in order to help you, but I wasn't able. While looking for solutions I found [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/215069364) report on [Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker). Google is already working on this behaviour, so now it is only a matter of time.

Comment: That's me haha!